# How to efficently parse a string of latitude/longitude points to an array of object in JS?

Tags: javascript

I receive a series of latitude/longitude points **in a string** (from a third party) with the following format (of course there can be more than 2 set of pairs):

```
[(49.0000, -105.0000), (49.0000, -110.0000)]
```

and I want to convert that string to an array of object like this:

```
[{lat: 49.0000, lng: -105.0000}, {lat: 49.0000, lng: -110.0000}]
```

I want to do this in pure JavaScript but would be open to use jQuery if it simplifies the code a lot.

Currently, I use some regex and substrings on the source string but I'm wondering if there more elegant way to do this conversion that I could have missed?

Comment: I guess you can replace all `(` with `{` and `)` with `}` then do JSON.parse(). But yes, to replace all you'll need regex.

Comment: You've tried something right? I mean a user with over 13K rep knows that they need to show what they tried that hasn't worked, correct?

Comment: @j08691 Yes it's a series of ugly substrings and string replace that everyone can do. My question is not about how to make my current code work but more "is there a more elegant way to do it".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```js
// your third party string
var string = '[(49.0000, -105.0000), (49.0000, -110.0000)]';

// make it a valid array of positions
// - basically changing parentheses to brackets
var array = string.replace(/[()]/g, function(d){
    return {
        '(' : '[',
        ')' : ']',
    }[d];
});

// now it is valid, parse it
array = JSON.parse(array);

// each item has lat/long in the positions 0/1, respectively
var result = array.map(function(item){
  return {
    lat: item[0],
    lng: item[1],
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `JSON.parse(dataString)` to achieve array of objects with lat/lng fields. If it's not solve your problem, than provide  addition information.